# ingresar una lista en webservice con asyntask

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

quisiera ingresar una lista de ventas del día en la web service, pero siempre me ingresa solo la primera linea de la lista. alguien tiene una idea?
esto va en variables globales y el oncreate del activity

```
    List<"OrdenDetalleEntity"> detalles;

detalles = new ArrayList<"OrdenDetalleEntity">();
```

guardo todo en detalles y lo mando al asyntask

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Object> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        OrdenDetalleDao odd = new OrdenDetalleDao();
        for(OrdenDetalleEntity ode: detalles){
            c++;
            ode.setLine(String.valueOf(c));
            try{
                odd.IngPedidoDetalle(ode.getOrdernum(), ode.getCustnum(), ode.getPartnum(), ode.getPartname(),
                        ode.getIum(),ode.getCompania(),ode.getLine(),ode.getTotalLinea(),ode.getPreciounitario(),
                        ode.getCantidad(),ode.getComentarioOrder(),ode.getCodPrecioLista(),ode.getPreciodolar(),ode.getPromo());

                res = odd.IngPedidoDetalle(ode.getOrdernum(), ode.getCustnum(), ode.getPartnum(), ode.getPartname(),
                        ode.getIum(),ode.getCompania(),ode.getLine(),ode.getTotalLinea(),ode.getPreciounitario(),
                        ode.getCantidad(),ode.getComentarioOrder(),ode.getCodPrecioLista(),ode.getPreciodolar(),ode.getPromo());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                res = e.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Object result){
        pd.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(!res.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Test1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            dSesion.numeroPedido = res;
            Toast.makeText(context, "Test2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Pedido Guardado Correctamente!: "+res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Test3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //Toast.makeText(context, "sale esto: "+"C0"+dSesion.companiaSesion, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //finish();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "El Pedido no se Realizó Correctamente",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: como estas llamando a este task? como llenas la lista?

Comment: @jirungaray estoy haciendo un for en el doInbackground. lo he actualizado

Comment: @jirungaray el bucle de enviar la lista está dentro del doInbackground, logra ingresar una linea, pero las demás no.

Comment: y como se arma esa lista? estas seguro que no tiene un solo elemento?

Comment: @jirunga  a la hora de buscar los productos los guardo en una clase y para recorrerlo lo asigno en una lista instanciada de esa clase. se llama detalles. sí tiene elementos, porque a la hora de guardar le pongo un Make.toast y me bota los valores de la última linea; y solo gaurda la primera. te puedo mandar todo el código? no aceptan por aquí los moderadores.

Comment: @ICRUZ Faltan muchos datos para poder ayudarte, pero veo cosas muy raras. Por ejemplo, el tipo de objeto de una Lista no lleva comillas, por tanto la lista quedaría `List<OrdenDetalleEntity>`, ya que es un objeto lo que le pasas no un `string`, lo mismo cuando la inicializas. Después, ¿Por qué devuelves 1 en el `doInBackground`?, creo que en vez de usar `res`como variable genérica, deberías pasársela directamente al `onPostExecute`.

Comment: @jirungaray lo de la lista no pude tipearlo aquí tal y como lo has hecho xD devuelvo 1 por el tipo de doinbackground que es entero porque devolverá un número. el res antes del catch? creo que se me pasó por andar haciendo cambios. me puedes ayudar por skype o teamviewer ?