# insertar registros por asynctask en una web service desde android

Tags: android, android-studio, webservice, android-asynctask

quiero insertar registros a una base de datos, pero que sea iterativa recorriendo una lista. y en cada recorrido insertar el registro.

se puede ejecutar el asynctask dentro de un for?
alguna ayuda por favor.

Comment: se puede ejecutar el asynctask dentro de un for? si pero esto no es recomendable, debes tener el "for" dentro de un asunctask

Comment: @Elenasys qué opinas de esto. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22782/ingresar-una-lista-en-webservice-con-asyntask?noredirect=1#comment36717_22782

Answer (score 1):

No tiene mucho sentido recorrer un bucle abriendo hilos y comunicarse con el servidor en cada uno de ellos, como sea un bucle muy grande va a fallar. En vez de eso puedes parsear esa lista y enviársela al servidor en una única llamada.

Lee más sobre el AsyncTask, en la propia [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) tienes algún ejemplo, yo te recomendaría incluso hacer tus propios ejemplos, estás orientándolo mal.

El método [doInBackground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) se encarga de realizar todas las tareas que tú le mandes en segundo plano, el qué y el cómo le es totalmente indiferente.

Comment: Mendez te entiendo. es lo que maso menos estoy haciendo. mira este enlace y dime qué te parece. gracias de antemano. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22782/ingresar-una-lista-en-webservice-con-asyntask?noredirect=1#comment36717_22782

Comment: Ya te he respondido en el otro hilo

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que `AsyncTask` ejecuta un hilo en segundo plano de tu aplicación. No es para nada recomendable que para cada inserción en tu base de datos crees un nuevo `hilo` en segundo plano, lo optimo es crear una tarea asíncrona que recorra todos los registros y haga los `inserts` correspondientes.

Con `AsyncTask` tienes la facilidad de enviar parametros a tu tarea y manejarlos.

El orden es más o menos asi

```
private class Insert extends AsyncTask<A, B, C>
```

Donde :

- A es parametros para el metodo `doInBackground`

El metodo `doInBackground` es el para mi, mas importante dentro de una tarea asincrona ya que se encarga de ejecutar todo tu codigo, aquí debe estar toda la logica de tu tarea de segundo plano. Por lo tanto es **AQUI** donde debes recibir tu arreglo, objeto, lista de los datos que quieres insertar en tu base de datos. Es aqui donde tienes que hacer un `for` para recorrerlos e insertarlos.

Si en tu caso es una `List<>` la que quieres enviar por parametro y recorrer deberia ser

```
private class Insert extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, B, C>

protected int doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... listaParametro) {
    int result = 1;
    try{
        for (int i=0; i<listaParametro.size(); i++) {
             System.out.println(listaParametro.get(i)); //Elemento iterado

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

- B es parametros para el metodo `onProgressUpdate`
- C es parametros para el metodo `onPostExecute`

El metodo `onPreExecute` no lleva parametros ya que se ejecuta antes de iniciar tu tarea, puedes inicializar variables.